# I can't figure out how to make PNG file with UV map

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I've am finishing up my model. But I want to paint the textures on it, but I don't understand how do I extract image with unwrapped object appearing on image so I would have some kind of guidelines on where should I paint[image: .]

Answer (score 1):

First, you should try the latest version of blender (2.81 at the moment), then just go the the UV menu (in the UV Editor) and select "Export UV Layout" : you 'll be asked to choose a file name, image type AND a resolution so you can paint on it in an external paint program.

[image: export UV layout to an image file]
But If you want, you can also just go the Texture Paint mode, create an empty texture Map and directly paint on your model ! Have Fun !